# Groovy: Convert string into Json object

Tags: groovy

I would like to convert the below string content into a Json object and get the values of `name and salary`.

```
def str = """
        [Employee[{
                        name=RIO,
                        age=22,
                        salary=2784165
        }],
        Employee[{
                        name=AMY,
                        age=24,
                        salary=10000
        }]]
    """
```

How would I do this in groovy(ONLY)? Need to get the salaries for a given name.

Comment: Why do you need json? DO you just need the salaries?

Comment: @1pluszara, why do you have string in such strange format? Is it possible to change format to json?

Comment: You don't _need_ to make it json to get the salaries. Do you need json? Or just the salaries? Or both?

Comment: Ps: what have you tried? Where did you come unstuck?

Comment: I guess you have to do some processing prior to use it as json. like removing line feeds, spaces, tokenizing and removing the 'Employee' strings. When you end up with a string like "{a},{b}" etc. it will be much better for processing

Comment: That "strange format" is most likely some `.toString()` along the way or something like that.  If you can not do anything about it, and you don't know what format that is (and reuse a parser for it), you have to write your own parser.  You can cheat maybe with some regexp action instead, but it's very likely upstream changes will ruin your cheat somehow.

Comment: Could you please provide an example, how this looks for e.g. a `name=...` where the name contains a `,` and some whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's one way to do it...

This assumes all records are exactly the same 5 lines long, with newlines and the first and last line of each group can be ignored:

```
def result = str.trim().split('\n')*.trim()
                .collate(5)
                .collect { it[1..-2].collectEntries { it.split('[=,]').take(2) } }
```

And result will be a list of maps:

```
[[name:RIO, age:22, salary:2784165], [name:AMY, age:24, salary:10000]]
```

Which then you can query as normal:

```
assert result.name == ['RIO', 'AMY']
```